# Vagrant up hangs on windows 10 machine on creating swap

Tags: windows, powershell, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I want to mount a vagrant machine on my **Windows 10**.
The machine runs on ubuntu 14.04.

However it just hangs for days literally when I run `vagrant up` either on powershell normal or admin.

These are the last lines(I can post all the messages if that helps):

```
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet::Python::Pip/Exec[easy_install pip]/returns: executed successfully
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_mailhog/Exec[download https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog/releases/download/v0.1.
8/MailHog_linux_amd64]/returns: executed successfully
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_php/Exec[mkdir -p /var/lib/php/session]/returns: executed successfully
==> local: Info: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_php/Exec[mkdir -p /var/lib/php/session]: Scheduling refresh of Service[php5-fpm]
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Puphpet_mailhog/File[/usr/local/bin/mailhog]/mode: mode changed '0644' to '0755' (+x)
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Group/Group[rvm]/ensure: created
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Rvmrc/File[/etc/rvmrc]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}e9df1edcb0b4c3710b33d429459
89928'
```

I run this on my **local ubuntu (NOT WINDOWS)** and runs fine.
The next line I get there is:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Swap_file/Exec[Create swap file]/returns: executed successfully
```

So I guess it hangs while creating the swap file.
However I don't have a clue how to solve this.

Any help?

Thank in advance

### UPDATE:

Running in **debug mode** it gets this extra messages:

```
==> local: Notice: /Stage[main]/Rvm::Rvmrc/File[/etc/rvmrc]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}e9df1edcb0b4c3710b33d429459
89928'
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
```

And keeps repeating `DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...`

Any help ?

Comment: Are you running cmd as admin?

Comment: the swap has been created .. it probably hangs after this. you can enable debug mode and see maybe more info about the command being executed

Comment: @FrédéricHenri are you taking into account that the `/Exec[Create swap file]/returns: executed successfully` is only what I get if  I run vagrant up on linux, right? maybe was not very clear...

Comment: Followed your advice @FrédéricHenri and updated the question, thank you!

Comment: do you have a ssh program on your windows machine so you can ssh into the VM

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes. but it does not accept the password vagrant for user vagrant and tried to reset it by entering the machine through VirtualBox GUI and got error Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Comment: did you check https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33196

Comment: yes but that leaves me with an incomplete initialized environment.. What I would really like is to get the normal `vagrant up` going